# node.js serialport module event types

Tags: node.js, serial-port

Is it possible to declare an event type when transmitting data in the way that socket.io allows. Currently writing with serialport is as:

```
serialPort.write("OMG IT WORKS\r");
```

which is received as:

```
serialPort.on("data", function (data) {
    foo(data);
});
```

i would like to transmit a number of different events e.g. "positionUpdate", "data", "timeSync" ..etc

e.g 
    serialPort.emit("positionUpdate", slavePosition);

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** It seems that [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) accepts an optional `parser`, which takes an `EventEmitter` and a raw buffer:

```
var myParser = function(emitter, buffer) {
  // Inspect buffer, emit on emitter:
  if(buffer.toString("utf8", 0, 3) === "foo")
    emitter.emit("foo", buffer);
  else
    emitter.emit("data", buffer);
};

var serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/foo", { parser: myParser });

serialport.on("foo", function(data) {
  // Do stuff
});
```

**Update:** Obviously, you will need to buffer the data that comes in, massage it in some way etc, but only you know what data to expect. You could take a look at [serialport's readline parser](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/blob/v1.7.1/parsers.js#L13-L28) as an introduction.

Without testing it, I think this is the better way, but I leave my initial solution below.

You could do this with a proxy:

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var SerialProxy = function(serialport){
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
  var self = this;
  serialport.on("data", function(data) {
    // Inspect data to see which event to emit
    // data is a Buffer object
    var prefix = data.toString("utf8", 0, 3);
    if(prefix === "foo")
      self.emit("foo", data.toString("utf8", 3));
    else if(prefix === "bar")
      self.emit("bar", data.toString("utf8", 3));
    else
      self.emit("data", data.toString("utf8"));
  });
};

util.inherits(SerialProxy, events.EventEmitter);
```

Usage:

```
var serialProxy = new SerialProxy(serialport);

serialProxy.on("foo", function(data) {
  // ...
});

serialProxy.on("bar", function(data) {
  // ...
});

serialProxy.on("data", function(data) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: no problems. The only edit required was to convert data to string as follows:
    data=data.toString(); then continue with rest of ....
    var prefix = data.substring(0, 3);
    if(prefix === "")
    etc

Comment: Great - I actually did that with the parser (the alternate solution after my first update, I actually recommend that way) but I'll update the other solution accordingly. Note: If there is lots of data, you might want to operate on the `Buffer` directly using `buffer.toString('utf8', 0, 3)` for example. See [node.js buffer docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffers.html).

Comment: Interesting, have you tested your updated solution?  options.parser(me, buffer)
                ^
TypeError: Property 'parser' of object #<Object> is not a function
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:82:17)

Comment: Strange, I have tested it here (with `/dev/urandom` as "serial port", since I don't have one...) and it works. Did you really specify it as `var serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/foo", { parser: myParser });`?

Comment: `var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

var serialPort1 = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyO1" , { parser: myParser } ); 
var serialPort2 = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyO2" , { parser: myParser } ); 

var myParser = function(emitter, buffer) {
  // Inspect buffer, emit on emitter:
  if(buffer.toString("utf8", 0, 3) === "foo")
    emitter.emit("foo", buffer);
  else
    emitter.emit("data", buffer);
};

serialPort2.on("foo", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

    
    setInterval( function(){
        serialPort1.write("footest");
        //console.log("msg sent");
    },2000);`

Comment: Try declaring `myParser` before you declare your serial ports, _or_ declare it as a `function` instead: `function myParser(emitter, buffer) { ... }`.